# Click on Edit button in GridView puts wrong row in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row, edit

I have gridview putting data from one table from database using stored procedure.
On click of Edit Button, post back is happen which refreshing the data on gridview and wrong row is shown in edir mode.

I have found the reason is that on click on EDIT link `javascript:__doPostBack('GridView','Edit$0')` is displayed at the status bar, which is a problem here. `Edit$0` means the absolute value of the row and when postback get the data from data base wrong row is shown in edit mode...

I think the solution will be put the edit mode based on not row number but some unique value of the selected row for edit.

Please help if any one has answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a gridview I suggest using the native OnRowEditing="GridViewEditEventHandler"
and then in the code behind

```
    protected void TaskGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    //Set the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
  }
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting(v=vs.110).aspx

However, if for some reason you are creating an OnClick function when you press the edit button and then changing the Itemtemplate to show/hide values I would suggest doing

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);


            int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
```

from there you can do the .findcontrol to find the specific item you want ex:
TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)TaskGridView.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("textBoxID");

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried OnRowEditing using the same link you have provided but it does not help. Also, the real issue happen when i click on edit link... suppose i have 5 in row in GV and while click edit on row 2, database table gets some new rows inserted or deleted from table so the row number changes and it puts the wrong row in edit mode since it does in based in row number.

Comment: If you are recreating the GV with new rows then you can reset your TaskGridView.EditIndex to the index you want on the data table. EX: you click row 2 and it inserts and deletes rows from the GV based on the database table. After, that happens set the editindex = to whichever row it is supposed to be based on whatever parameters you have

Comment: Setting TaskGridView.EditIndex does not help as it still consider the same row number on which edit was clicked earlier but now with GV getting refreshed and new data in table can change that row number to anything else... but it still edit the same row number which could not have some other data.